# Re-programming button found at thrift store

Tags: circuit-analysis, pcb

I found this cheap button at a thrift store and want to change the sound it plays when you press it; currently it plays through a cycle of around 10 audio clips, about 4 seconds each, each time you press it (one four second clip each press). I’m wondering if anyone has ever tackled anything like this?

There’s a very simple circuit where everything of interest looks to be on a chip on board, however it does look like there are two points on the PCB meant to interface with. I have a mid-low level understanding of small electronics, know how to navigate arduino and have a basic arsenal of tools such as voltmeter, soldering iron, etc.

Anyone know how to start here? Maybe removing the resin if noone has seen anything like this?

[image]

[image]

Comment: You would have to remove the epoxy while still preserving the markings to read the part number on the chip (unlikely). Then locate its datasheet. And even if you managed to do that, you will probably find out the chip is only one-time programmable then you're out of luck.

Comment: You're wasting your time. Underneath that blob is a bare silicon die (so there are no part markings there to read). Removing the epoxy would also destroy the fine wires bonded between the die and the PCB since they're embedded in the epoxy. Even if you could disassemble it you'd find that the sounds it plays are hard-coded (probably mask ROM).

Comment: There's only 1 company in TW that I know of who makes these but I forgot their name.

Comment: aha Windbond  https://media.digikey.com/pdf/Data%20Sheets/Winbond%20PDFs/ISD5116.pdf   See if you can reprogram it with this info

Comment: @TonyStewartSunnyskyguyEE75 is it something like Unicorn audio?  Rhinocerous audio?  (I don't remember either.)

Answer (score 4):

Forget it, these are mask-programmed or OTP chips that cannot be changed. Even worse they're COB construction from one of many mainland China chip companies that probably don't even have English datasheets.

Cut out the board out and replace it with an inexpensive Chinese module that uses MP3 or other easily created sound file format. Either with an SD card or USB port to program. You can re-use the speaker, switch and enclosure.